# Activeadmin disabling the "new resource" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using Activeadmin for the admin interface on an app I'm working on (loving it) and I am curious if there is a way to disable the "New Resource" link in the upper-right corner of the resource show page?

The particular resource I'm using is nested inside another resource and I have a partial that allows it to be created from the show page on that parent resource.

I have disabled the resource in the menu, but I'd rather leave the resource in the menu so I can see/edit/delete those resources without having to find it by looking through its parent resource.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `config.clear_action_items!` to remove the link to `New` and other links on top of the table

Comment: That right there did it. Thank you very much. In the event that I want to have items in the action menu, do I just add them after I clear it?

Comment: in the index menu adding "default_actions" works to get view/edit/delete actions

Comment: I got this:


undefined method `clear_action_items!' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x00000103447628> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @makaroni4 you have to call it inside the DSL.

Comment: `actions :index` or `actions:all, :except ...` is recommended and documented.

Answer (score 70):

Previous solution didn`t work for me, so here is general solutions, that works always:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  actions :index

  #or like that
  #actions :all, :except => [:destroy]

  index do
    column :title
    column :author
  end  
end
```

Comment: `actions :index` did not work for me, but `actions :all, :except => [:new]` did the job.

Answer (score 28):

This removed the "New Resource" button from the top-right:

```
    config.clear_action_items!
```

This removed both the "New Resource" button as well as the box "There are no resources yet - create one".

```
    actions :all, :except => [:new]
```

Thank you, Irio

Comment: Small note here.  If you define a custom controller and define `new` inside of the controller block, that will override this setting.  Just learned that one.  If you specify that a certain action shouldn't exist, ensure you do not also define it in a `controller` block!

Answer (score 15):

```
config.clear_action_items!
```

Will remove all the actions.
If you only want to remove the new action link you can also use:

```
config.remove_action_item(:new)
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I just came up to it (had the same problem), and realized that `config.clear_action_items!` and `actions :all, :except => [:new]` are fundamentally different.

`config.clear_action_items!` will remove the `New` button from the index page, while `actions :all, :except => [:new]` will remove both the button, AND the route, meaning you can't call it from another place (which, in my case, is needed).

Answer (score 7):

I did this:

```
controller do
  def action_methods
    if some_condition
      super
    else
      super - ['new', 'create', 'destroy']
    end
  end
end
```

To disable some of the possible actions. **action_methods** returns an array of the 7 standard CRUD actions, so you can subtract those you don’t want

Answer (score 4):

Or even:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Purchase do
  config.clear_action_items!
  actions :index
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`config.clear_action_items!` does only half of the job. There is one issue though.

In case of empty index table, active admin show this message

> There are no [Resources] yet. Create one

which doesn't get hidden by the above command and I don't want to entirely disable the action. So, I kept the link and edited the new action to redirect to the parent resource index with a message.

```
controller do
  def new
    if params[:parent_id].present?
      super
    else
      redirect_to parent_resources_path, notice: "Create Resource through ParentResource"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Worked for me too ! :-) 

ActiveAdmin.register AssetSumView do
             menu :label => "Asset Summary View", :parent => "Things"
# no button for NEW (since this is a db view)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
config.clear_action_items!

    enter code here

   action_item do
      link_to "Assets" , "/admin/assets" 
    end

   action_item do
      link_to "AssetCatgCodes", "/admin/asset_catg_codes"
    end

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```